# Downloading direct .7z file from python 3 is corrupted

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I am making a program to download .7z files from mega.nz.
I need a direct link to the file, but public link generators are giving me a 403 Forbidden error, so I have created my own link generator. My problem is that my generated link leads to a corrupted .7z file.
I have confirmed that the .7z file works via manual download.

Python 3 code

```
# self.file_url is the direct link to mega.nz file generated using my php code
urlretrieve(self.file_url, self.save_path, self.showProgress)
```

PHP code

```
<?php

if ($_GET) {

error_reporting(0);
$url = $_GET['URL'];
preg_match("/!(.+?)!/", $url, $output_array);
$fileID = $output_array[1];
$domain = "meganz";
$lang = "en";
$apiURL = "https://eu.api.mega.co.nz/cs?domain=$domain&lang=$lang";

$value = array(
  array(
    'a' => 'g',
    'g' => 1,
    'ssl' => 0, //0, 1, 2 (default is 2)
    'p' => $fileID) // File id here
  );

  $rawPOST = json_encode($value);

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $apiURL );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $rawPOST );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'));

  $result=curl_exec($ch);

  $jsonResult = json_decode($result);
  $directLink = $jsonResult[0]->g;
  $fileSize = $jsonResult[0]->s;

  echo $directLink;
} else {
    echo '<html><head><title>Mega downloader</title></head><body><h2>Enter Url</h2><form action="mega-direct.php"> <br> URL: <input type="text" name="URL"> <br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Aw common, nobody has an answer to this? Normally I would have at least a comment in the first 3 hours the question is asked

Comment: HELLO?! Why is nobody helping?

Comment: The file is encrypted.